# setState does not set the state properly, when dropdown values changes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, setstate, semantic-ui-react

I am having this scenario, where I have a dropdown which pulls the accounts of a user and then based on its selection the content of the page changes. I am trying an approach which is shown below , It seems like setState does not get invoked properly or may be calling sequence may be wrong. Not really getting what is wrong. Changing drop down value does not update the content .

Help would be appreciated.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Select from 'semantic-ui-react/dist/commonjs/addons/Select';

interface IState{
  accountDetails[], // stores all details w.r.t an account
  userAccounts: [], // stores all accounts w.r.t a user
  selectedAccount : string, // selected account from the dropdown
  [x: string] : any,
}

export default class App extends React.Component<{},IState> {

  constructor(props:any){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      accountDetails: [],
      userAccounts: [],
      selectedAccount: ''
    }
  }

  dropdownChange = (event: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLElement>, data:any) => {
     this.setState(prevState => ({
      selectedAccount: data.value
     }), () => {});
  }

  async componentDidMount()
  {
      await this.fetchUserAccounts();
  }  


  fetchUserAccounts = async() => {
    //fetch API call for getting all user accounts by passing a user ID
    // I am able to get the data
    fetch('/api/fetch/accounts'
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ userAccounts: data}));
    this.fetchAccountDetails();
  }    

  fetchAccountDetails = async() =>
  {
       let URL = "/api/fetch/account?accountId=" +this.state.selectedAccount;
       fetch('URL'
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({ accountDetails: data}));
  }

  render() {
    return(
       <div>
         <Select 
                 options={this.state.userAccounts} 
                 name="selectedAccount"  
                 value={this.state.selectedAccount}
                 onChange={this.dropdownChange}                         
        />
        // component to display the details
        <DetailComponent accounts={this.state.accountDetails} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: When dropdown changes, you are not calling `fetchAccountDetails` function again to fethch the account details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `fetchAccountDetails` right after changing the state, for the function to invoke using the latest state that the dropdown has changed:

```
  dropdownChange = (event: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLElement>, data:any) => {
     this.setState(prevState => ({
      selectedAccount: data.value
     }), () => { this.fetchAccountDetails() });
  }
```

Comment: Yeah able to get account details corresponding to an account. But next time if I change the dropdown value, the details are getting replicated.Like the copy of previously fetched account details gets replicated

Comment: Can you please elaborate - What do you mean by "replicated"? If you change the dropdown to a different value, what happens?

Comment: If I have two values in the account say 1 and 2, where in 1 has data and 2 has got no data. If I select 1 from dropdown data shows up and later If I select 2 then first data does not get cleared up(even though I get no results for 2 from back end). Next time again If I select 1 , the same content of 1 gets added up to the previous data.

Comment: Please post the results you get from your API & the code of `DetailComponent`.

Comment: You should also try to debug what happens in the scenarios you just specified. Use `console.log(data)` etc.

Answer (score 0):

the `setState` function is asynchronous, which means you need to take special precaution when updating state and expecting to use the updated value in the state synchronously. For this reason, the `setState` function has a second parameter which allows you to specify a callback which is executed when the state has actually been updated. This is where you would need to call the `fetchAccountDetails` function.

You can find the `setState` callback parameter described in the React docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

But you will have trouble compiling this either way. (a) Your interface should end each member declaration with a semicolon, not a comma. (b) You're missing a ")" on each line with a call to `fetch`. (c) In the `fetchAccountDetails` function you declare the `URL` variable, but then you pass a string 'URL' to the `fetch` function, not the variable.

Here is a working code sandbox showing the fix to your question,  and the syntax fixes. I've commented out the calls to the `fetch` function since they will fail anyway.

https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-rain-2u69e